# Calculate the average by criteria (name and contract period)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database

I have a dataset that resembles the following:

```
name  year contracted-period salary
peter 2012 2012-2014         $65
peter 2013 2012-2014         $70
peter 2014 2012-2014         $90
tom   2012 2012-2013         $110
tom   2013 2012-2013         $140
```

What i want is to create a new column that has the average salary for each name over that contract period i.e. each row in the column for peter would have his average salary over the contract

```
name  year contracted-period salary average-per-contract
peter 2012 2012-2014         $65    $75
peter 2013 2012-2014         $70    $75
peter 2014 2012-2014         $90    $75
tom   2012 2012-2013         $110   $125
tom   2013 2012-2013         $140   $125
```

I imagine the formula will have something to do with averageifs but i haven't been able to work it out.

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 2):

If your data table starts in A1, then the following in cell E2 will work (then fill down):

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$6,A2,$D$2:$D$6)
```

(assumes you have data only for the contracted period, and 1 contract period per person)

If you have more than 1 contract period per person, add a helper column to make a unique ID in column E:

```
=A2&"_"&C2
```

Then run the sum equation on that ID instead of name:

```
=AVERAGEIF($E$2:$E$8,E2,$D$2:$D$8)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. What about when each person has multiple contracts. For instance, if peter also had a 2015-2016 contract in the data set?